# Bash on Interix causes segfault for any command

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault, sua, interix

What could cause BASH commands to produce a segmentation fault when run from Interix v3.5?
BASH was installed as [directed](http://www.suacommunity.com/pkg_install.htm) by SUA.
In experimentation, I've only encountered 'cd' functioning as expected.

```
[computer src] ??? ls
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[computer src] ??? cd ..
[computer project] ??? uname
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[computer project] ??? find . | sort
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[computer project] ??? ps auwwx | grep program | grep user
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: v3.5 appears to be intended for Windows 2000.  What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Im running windows XP-Pro SP3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SUAcommunity FAQ's](http://www.suacommunity.com/FAQs.htm#207) the segmentation fault is due to bash triggering a DEP or a Data Execution Prevention. The suggested fix is installing the [KB942312](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=942312) hotfix. However, according to [SUAcommunity forums](http://www.suacommunity.com/forum2/archive/index.php?thread-1728.html), this is not sufficient and the [KB953191](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=953191) hotfix should also be installed. After following these steps, bash functioned properly on Interix 3.5.